# How to approach finding Big O /Time complexity of any algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

All,

I have always found myself being doubtful when it comes to finding the complexity of a given code/algorithm. Ex.

```
FOR I=1 TO N
do J=1
WHILE J*J < I
do J=J+1
```

The above code has time complexity of `Big Theta (N^(3/2))` . However, I don't understand how the answer is derived.

Can anyone please guide me to the steps for finding the complexity or any specific resource that can help me? Most of the times, I only find code with complexity `N, lg N , N lg N` and `N^2`

Comment: The example you gave is not Big-Oh, it's Big-Theta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach is always the same: work out how many operations are being executed as a function of *N*, and then throw away low-order terms and constants.

So in your example above, the inner loop iterates approximately *sqrt(I)* times, so we have (approximately) *sqrt(1)* + *sqrt(2)* + *sqrt(3)* + ...  The result is a function whose highest-order term is *N*^(3/2).